# python related plugins give errors in vim

Tags: windows, vim, python

So here's an example of a vim plugin having python issues:

```
Error detected while processing function UltiSnipsEdit:
line    6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\2c.2c2c\.vim\bundle\ultisnips\plugin\UltiSnips\__init__.py", line 981, in file_to_edit
    os.mkdir(path)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: u'C:\\Users\\2c.2c2c\\vimfiles\\UltiSnips'
line   16:
E121: Undefined variable: file
E15: Invalid expression: ':'.mode.' '.file
```

Errors similar to this from vim plugin makers all say this is an issue with your python environment. I have the latest 27x and 3xx builds of python and use a precompiled vim from http://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/. I've uninstalled/reinstalled one or the other version, installed both versions, both with and without paths set. Nothing seems to have an effect.

> :version

returns python/dyn for both versions, although I've messed with changing paths/uninstalling-reinstalling to have them alone and not alone etc. To see if anything changes. Also, basic python appears to actually work, I can do

> :python print ("hello")

with no issue.

I'm also kind of confused why it's checking that directory... Vundle adds rtps to ~/.vim/bundle/addon for anything it installs.

Anyways, I haven't seen anyone with an issue like this on Windows, so none of the information is very helpful. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error originates from the function `files_to_edit()` in file "C:\Users\2c.2c2c.vim\bundle\ultisnips\plugin\UltiSnips__init__.py". Given a filetype (e.g, "markdown") this function tries figure out where the file with corresponding snippets ("markdown.snippets") might be located in your system. The function checks several places:

1. If global variable `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` exists, then it looks in that folder
2. If global variable `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` exists, then it iterates over the items in `rtp`, appends the directory from the variable, and looks in the resulting folders
3. If none of the above is set, then it iterates over the items in `rtp`, appends "UltiSnips" , and looks in the resulting folders

According to your error message

> WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
>   u'C:\Users\2c.2c2c\vimfiles\UltiSnips'

it ended up in the third option. For some reason, it did not pick up the correct item from `rtp`. What you could do to fix the problem without digging into the plugin source code and debugging it is set `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` explicitly to the location where the snippets are stored, i.e. "C:\Users\2c.2c2c.vim\bundle\ultisnips\UltiSnips". Just drop the line

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = "C:\Users\2c.2c2c\.vim\bundle\ultisnips\UltiSnips"
```

somewhere in your .vimrc.